# Copy lStream to byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, filestream

```cpp
HRESULT hr = URLOpenBlockingStreamW(nullptr, cstring, &pStream, 0, nullptr);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return 1;
}

char buffer[4096];
do
{
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    hr = pStream->Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead);
        
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        std::cout.write(buffer, bytesRead);
    }
        
} while (SUCCEEDED(hr) && hr != S_FALSE);

//memcpy(&bytesRead, arr, sizeof(buffer));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return 2;
}

return 0;
```

What I used to do was download the file and read from there, but now I'm trying to directly download the file into memory. I don't need to be spoon-fed. I'm quite new to this, and would like an explanation, if anything, so I can actually learn it. The only example I found was the code above. I don't understand how to copy the bytes to a byte array directly from the stream. (or how to get the exact file size from a file on a website).

In C#, it was a lot easier to just download the file to a path and use
`File.ReadAllBytes(path);`

**EDIT:** this is in C++, not C# like the old one (if you couldn't tell from the code snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IStream` has a [`Stat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-istream-stat) method for querying the size of the stream (among other things).  Query the size, then allocate a byte array of that size, then `Read()` into the array.

If `Stat()` cannot determine the size (because the download is streaming and doesn't know the full size up front), then just use a `std::vector` as your byte array, so that it will grow as you write more bytes to it.

```cpp
HRESULT hr = URLOpenBlockingStreamW(nullptr, cstring, &pStream, 0, nullptr);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return 1;

std::vector<char> bytes;

STATSTG stat = {};
hr = pStream->Stat(&stat, STATFLAG_NONAME | STATFLAG_NOOPEN);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    size_t size = stat.cbSize.QuadPart;
    if (size > 0)
    {
        bytes.resize(size);
        char *buffer = bytes.data();
        DWORD bytesRead;

        do
        {
            hr = pStream->Read(buffer, size, &bytesRead);
            if (FAILED(hr))
                return 2;

            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;

            buffer += bytesRead;
            size -= bytesRead;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    do
    {
        hr = pStream->Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead);
        if (FAILED(hr)
            return 3;

        if (bytesRead == 0)
            break;

        bytes.insert(bytes.end(), buffer, buffer + bytesRead);
    }
    while (true);
}

// use bytes as needed...

return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, im pretty new to this so idk how to thumbs up or +rep you